# Visual Studio 2017 C# Как отключить автозавершение IntelliSense по пробелу?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Visual Studio 2017 C# Как отключить автозавершение IntelliSense по пробелу?
Visual studio 2017 15.7.3

Comment: нашел решение? мне тоже не помог ответ

Answer (score 1):

В Visual Studio:

> Edit->IntelliSense->Toggle Completion Mode(Ctrl+Alt+Space)

или просто нажми <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Эта настройка не помогает.

Comment: У меня та же версия VS, все работает.